# Zimbra inbox unable to receive emails from other servers

Tags: ubuntu, email, imap, smtp, zimbra

I have setup a zimbra server on an ubuntu VM, opened up the necessary ports according to this [tutorial](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/set-up-zimbra-mail-server-ubuntu-18-04).

I am able to receive emails from gmail or outlook using other email domains.

However, no emails are received when I sign-up for services that send confirmation emails or alerts. For example, I tried signing up for a newsletter using the email address that the zimbra server is using but no email to confirm the account was ever sent. More so, there are no logs showing whether the email even came through to the zimbra server.

Comment: How long ago did you set up your domain's MX record? Has it had time to propagate yet? If you `dig @1.1.1.1 mx contoso.com` (replacing `contoso.com` with your own domain), and then repeat the process at `8.8.8.8` and `9.9.9.9` do they all return the correct value? Have you set up SPF, DKIM, and DMARC, and if so, again how much time have you given the DNS records to propagate?